$\mathcal{H}_\delta^s$ is not a metric outer measure
I want to prove that, in general, $\mathcal{H}_\delta^s$ is not a metric outer measure, meaning that $\mathcal{H}_\delta^s(A\cup B)\neq\mathcal{H}_\delta^s(A)+\mathcal{H}_\delta^s(B)$ for some sets $A$ and $B$ with $d(A,B)>0$. Does this boil down to the fact that if we aren't in the limiting case $\delta\to0^+$, then for a sufficiently large $\delta$, the covering sets can intersect both $A$ and $B$, or is there a more subtle idea to it?

In certain cases, it is a metric outer measure.  On $\mathbb R$, the usual definition of Lebesgue outer measure does not require $\delta \to 0$.  So, $\mathcal H^1_\delta$ is metric for any fixed  $\delta$.  But of course $\mathcal H^s_\delta$ is not metric on $\mathbb R$ for $s<1$.

@GEdgar Yes, I know, that's why I said "in general" or "for certain $s$". But how would  you go about proving that $\mathcal{H}_\delta^1$ is not metric for $s<1$?

@GEdgar Or does the proof in the case where $s<1$ depend on the fact that taking a small $\delta$ to the power of $s$ makes it bigger?

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can take the two segments $[(0,0), (0,1)]$ and $[(\varepsilon, 0), (\varepsilon, 1)]$ for an $\varepsilon$ much less than $\delta$ and $1$. You can cover this set by a circle with diameter $\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^2}$, which is less than $2$. If $\delta<\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^2}$, then you can cover by smaller circles, or just make the segments shorter. This example also shows that $\mathcal{H}_\delta^1$ is not the usual length on the plane.
